# Im getting my coordinates but the state of 'data' isnt updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, weather

I'm trying to make a simple react weather app that gets the users current location using geolocation method. And I want the api to wait to display until it retrieves their coordinates. It gets my coordinates and the data but it doesn't update the state of the 'data' value. Perhaps I'm not pointing to the correct key/value or something.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-shockley-gimek?) 
[Data is retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M66BY.png)

Comment: if you `console.log(data)` just before your setState you would notice that you are attempting to retrieve values that do not exist. `data.data[0].city_name` gets the city name from the response (you will probably want to run checks to make sure there is data returned)

Comment: yea. the response is {data : [] , count: 1}. so you will have to dig one level down and use data.data to get city_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're request is working you just aren't parsing the response properly. If you have a look in the console, you can see the data response is an object containing an array called data. You are trying to assign your city value to a property that doesn't exist in the root object but rather in the object contained in the data array.

Try changing this:

```
const data = await api_call.json();

this.setState({
  latitude: latitude,
  longitude: longitude,
  city: data.city_name,
  data: data,
  isLoaded: true
});
```

to this:

```
const {data} = await api_call.json();

this.setState({
  latitude: latitude,
  longitude: longitude,
  city: data[0].city_name,
  data: data[0],
  isLoaded: true
});
```

It would also be wise to try and handle 0 or more than 1 objects in the `data` array.

---

It's also worth mentioned that this line:

```
const {data} = await api_call.json();
```

is called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and is the same as doing this:

```
let data = await api_call.json();
data = data.data;
```